# Why did Community decide to delete this question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

Deleted question: [How can I show by Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523634/how-can-i-show-that-by-induction/523638#523638)

The best reason that I can see, is that it got 3 down votes and 0 up votes. Was that the trigger?

Comment: Perhaps the account was "nuked"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I thought so, but [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521778/dividing-square-of-2013x2013) posted by the user remains up.

Comment: I am looking into it.

Answer (score 13):

The user was deleted.  When that happens, their negatively voted questions are deleted, too. There is [some debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860) as to whether this should be done when there are upvoted answers.  I will undelete the question since there are upvoted answers.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: There is a bounty from the Community user which ends in a day or so, which seems to have been started by the original poster. Is this the way active bounties started by deleted users are generally handled?