# Can a question having upvoted answer be auto-deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user, auto-delete

I thought that the question with an upvoted answer cannot be auto-deleted. (And that it can be deleted only by votes of users who have [privilege to vote for deletion](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).)

In faq entry [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) it says about the deletion by the system:

> ### By the system:
>
> 6. [The system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will automatically delete any post [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow) six times as > offensive or spam.
> 7. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.
> 8. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
> 9. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
> 10. The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.
> 11. The system will automatically delete questions migrated to other sites [after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082).

If I did not miss something, the only case is if the owner's account is deleted and score is less than zero (the fifth point). This happened, for example, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/why-did-community-decide-to-delete-this-question).

However, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877499/express-sinx-sqrt3-cosx-in-the-form-a-sinx-a) was autodeleted, the user still exists and it has one upvoted answer. It was closed but if I understand correctly the second point (which mentions deleting questions *having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes*), if there is upvoted answer, it should not be deleted.

Screenshot showing the state of that particular question at the moment:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upvoted answer was deleted by its author. Deleted answers are not considered by automatic deletion scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I should have noticed that. This explains this particular case. (So I suppose that I was right in thinking that a question with an upvoted answer cannot be auto-deleted. Only in this case I did not notice that the answer had already been deleted at the time of auto-deletion.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, a positively scored answer would prevent automatic deletion otherwise.

Comment: Is it that a *positively scored* answer prevents auto-deletion or an *upvoted* answer prevents auto-deletion?

Comment: @Isaac Positively scored. If upvotes are canceled with downvotes, the auto-deletion applies. This is why we had [this lovely discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15126/).